# Really basic query returning no results in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to bugfix a search implementation backed by Elasticsearch 1.7.x. The main problem we're having is with the relevance of search results returned.

For various reasons, I'm trying out some very basic queries (I mean *this* basic: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/query-dsl-intro.html) from the command line.

I have an index containing two documents, as follows:

```
{  
   "took":1,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":2,
      "max_score":1.0,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"merchantv2",
            "_type":"searchablemerchant",
            "_id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{  
               "merchantGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
               "v1MerchantId":0,
               "locatorId":"0",
               "address":{  
                  "addressGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                  "postCodeDetails":{  
                     "postCodeKey":0,
                     "postalDistrict":{  
                        "postalDistrictKey":0,
                        "postalDistrict":""
                     },
                     "postalLocation":"0",
                     "latitude":0.0,
                     "longitude":0.0,
                     "townName":"None",
                     "countyKey":0,
                     "countryKey":0,
                     "postCode":{  
                        "postCodeKey":0,
                        "postCode":" 0"
                     }
                  },
                  "county":{  
                     "countyKey":0,
                     "countyName":"",
                     "countryKey":0,
                     "recStatus":3,
                     "countryKeyValue":0
                  },
                  "countryKey":0,
                  "addressTypeKey":0,
                  "updateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "createdDate":"2016-01-07T19:46:28.4463+00:00"
               },
               "searchableAddress":" 0",
               "searchablePhone":"",
               "searchableFax":"",
               "businessName":"",
               "contacts":[  

               ],
               "opportunities":[  
                  {  
                     "opportunityGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                     "merchantGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                     "location":{  
                        "locationGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                        "tradingAddress":{  
                           "verified":false,
                           "addressGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                           "postCodeDetails":{  
                              "postCodeKey":0,
                              "postalDistrict":{  
                                 "postalDistrictKey":0,
                                 "postalDistrict":""
                              },
                              "postalLocation":"0",
                              "latitude":0.0,
                              "longitude":0.0,
                              "townName":"None",
                              "countyKey":0,
                              "countryKey":0,
                              "postCode":{  
                                 "postCodeKey":0,
                                 "postCode":" 0"
                              }
                           },
                           "county":{  
                              "countyKey":0,
                              "countyName":"",
                              "countryKey":0,
                              "recStatus":3,
                              "countryKeyValue":0
                           },
                           "countryKey":0,
                           "addressTypeKey":0,
                           "updateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                           "createdDate":"2016-01-07T19:46:28.4463+00:00"
                        }
                     },
                     "opportunityLocatorId":"000000"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "_index":"merchantv2",
            "_type":"searchablemerchant",
            "_id":"5f55fe61-ca65-e411-93f3-0cc47a07ef4a",
            "_score":1.0,
            "_source":{  
               "merchantGuid":"5f55fe61-ca65-e411-93f3-0cc47a07ef4a",
               "locatorId":"PM227Z02",
               "address":{  
                  "addressGuid":"5c55fe61-ca65-e411-93f3-0cc47a07ef4a",
                  "houseNumber":"242",
                  "streetName":"Acklam Road",
                  "houseName":"",
                  "flatAptSuite":"",
                  "townName":"London",
                  "postCodeDetails":{  
                     "postCodeKey":1,
                     "postalDistrict":{  
                        "postalDistrictKey":2782,
                        "postalDistrict":"W10"
                     },
                     "postalLocation":"5JJ",
                     "latitude":51.52094651,
                     "longitude":-0.20149990,
                     "townName":"London",
                     "countyKey":0,
                     "countryKey":224,
                     "postCode":{  
                        "postCodeKey":1,
                        "postCode":"W10 5JJ"
                     }
                  },
                  "county":{  
                     "countyKey":626,
                     "countyName":"Kensington And Chelsea",
                     "countryKey":224,
                     "recStatus":1,
                     "countryKeyValue":224
                  },
                  "countryKey":224,
                  "addressTypeKey":0,
                  "updateDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
                  "createdDate":"2016-01-07T19:46:28.4653+00:00"
               },
               "searchableAddress":"242 Acklam Road, London, Kensington And Chelsea, W10 5JJ",
               "searchablePhone":"+44 2031954484",
               "searchableFax":"",
               "businessName":"Test Merchant",
               "contacts":[  

               ],
               "opportunities":[  

               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to query against the `businessName` field. I'm using the following query from the command line:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/merchantv2/_search -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "businessName": "test"
        }
    }
}'
```

I'd expect that to match the document whose `businessName` is set to "Test Merchant", but in fact I get no matches returned:

```
{"took":45,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

I get a similar result with the following search terms: `test*`, `*test*`, `Test`, `Test Merchant`, `test merchant`.

Given that `businessName` is a top level property I'm somewhat perplexed by this. Does anyone have any ideas, please?

**EDIT - Forgot to include the mapping**

Here's the mapping for the `businessName` field:

```
           "businessName":{  
              "type":"string"
           },
```

Comment: You're not going to delete this one, right? ;-)

Comment: Haha - no. I don't think it's just a typo in this case.

Comment: Your question was still useful as it is a very common mistake many people do, anyway... What is the mapping for the `businessName` field?

Comment: Fair point. I wonder if I can undelete it - I'll have a look. I've added the businesssName mapping to the question.

Comment: Note that `match` queries don't support wildcards (i.e. `test*` and `*test*`), though the other four should work. <thinking />

Comment: Can you try to use `-XPOST` instead of `-XGET` since you're sending a payload?

Comment: Interesting. The code I have in front of me has a wildcard query in it (although doesn't utilise match or multi-match because it's across all fields) because we need to be able to match the start of words, e.g., "Rose" should match "Rosewood Hotel". I'll have another dig through the docs and see if I can do that on queries against specific fields. As you say, still doesn't explain why "test" doesn't work.

Comment: See this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-match-query.html#_comparison_to_query_string_field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after digging out the index configuration. The index is built at runtime using NEST, and it looks like it's stripping whitespace characters during the analysis. Hence, as Val's pointed out for wildcards, `match` would never work because it needs to be an exact match.

`match_phrase_prefix` does work until you try something like "test mer", or "mer", neither of which return any results. However, "testmer" does return a match.

Here's the offending section of the configuration:

```
             .Analysis(descriptor => descriptor
                .Analyzers(bases => bases
                    .Add("trimmed_specChars", new CustomAnalyzer()
                    {
                        CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_specChars" },
                        Tokenizer = "standard",
                        Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "lowercase" }
                    })
                    .Add("no_whitespace", new CustomAnalyzer() // <-- Bad times
                    {
                        CharFilter = new List<string> { "drop_whiteSpace" },
                        Tokenizer = "standard",
                        Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase", "asciifolding", "lowercase" }
                    })
                 ).CharFilters(cf => cf
                    .Add("drop_specChars", new PatternReplaceCharFilter
                    {
                        Pattern = @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]",
                        Replacement = ""
                    })
                    .Add("drop_whiteSpace", new PatternReplaceCharFilter() // <-- Also bad times
                    {
                        Pattern = @" ",
                        Replacement = ""
                    })

                )
```

I might be off the mark here but I feel like stripping whitespace is unnecessary and that the search would work more reliably if this wasn't done, so I'm going to experiment with that.